# Probability Density Functions (Find C1)

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, density-function

Let R be the region inside both loops of the function $r = 2+4\cos(θ)$. Then I was first asked to find the value of $C_1$ so that $f(r,θ)$ is a joint density function. So, $f(r,θ) = C_1(1-r^2)$ , if $(r,θ)∈R$ but the issue is I am not exactly sure how to do this in my mind I am thinking I could integrate over the function $1-r^2$ first and then $2+4\cos(θ)$ to find the ratio but no text book does this.

So how exactly should I go about this because all the examples in my text book provides bounds which makes it easy but this one does not. I know I can find the bounds easy but I am not sure what I am looking for should I just use the bounds of the function $z = 1-r^2$ for all parts thats inside the function $r=2+4\cos(θ)$?

Here is a screen shot of the problem.

Comment: What does $(r,\theta) \in R$ mean?

Comment: I included everything that was given in my problem

Comment: How exactly would I find the value of C1 what?

Comment: You would find $C_1$ by solving the equation $$\iint_{R}fdA=1$$I just don't know what $R$ represents since your polar curve graphs a limacon with an inner and outer loop

Comment: R is the region inside the big and small loop of the limacon

Comment: After I find C1 my goal is to find the probability of the inner loop but I can probably do that I just dont know how to set up the integral to solve for C1.

Comment: Are you sure you have the function $f$ correct? No matter what value you assign to $C_1$ your $f$ is going to take on both positive and negative values inside $R$ which means it cannot be a valid pdf.

Comment: Yes that is the correct function and I have this assignment  due tonight... Is there a way I could post a screen shot of the problems wording?

Comment: I included a screen shot let me know if that helps

Comment: Edit the screenshot in your original post. Your pdf is a paraboloid that opens down if $C_1>0$ and up if $C_1<0$. It crosses the $xy-$plane along the unit circle $r=1$ so you'll always be able to find points inside $R$ for which $f>0$ and $f<0$ which means it cannot be a valid pdf

Comment: Then what am I suppose to do? Its a multi question problem which means the others depend on the answer from part a

Comment: So if a pdf is in the +y and -y portion of the graph its not valid? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120216/discussion-between-matthew-pilling-and-unsure).